# EJB, WebService combined with JNI scenario

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, ejb

i'm working on a project, where i have to decide to use EJB, Webservices or EJB with `@WebService` in a combined way. I'm new to Java EE and i like the concept of EJBs, but i want also provide a way for non-java-systems to use this service. Here are the facts about the major components:

- There are components, which have to interact with the database (simple DAOs) and a little bit more aggregated inserts. They should be called only from other java components
- I have component(s), which are using shared library on the application server with complex calculations. This library depends on two native Libraries. So i have to use JNI. In the literature, they said, that it is not recommend to work with EJBs and native libraries together (i don't know why). But in this case i have no other chance. These component(s) needs to interact with the DAOs and have to be available for non-java applications.
- The resulting architecture should be expandable (with timer services in EJB or some other functionalities)

The plan was to implement all these components in EJBs, but the point with the native library is confusing me. So my question is now:

- How should i implement the components with all the database stuff? (I would use EJB, because of the Pooling and the transaction stuff)
- How should i implement the component(s), which are using the native library through JNI, but also have to interact with the database? (Jax-WS WebService, EJB declared as JAX-WS service?

Another option would be to put everything in one single WebService. But i would not like this approach, because of the transactional an pooling advantages in EJB and the restricted expandability. So i would be greatful, if you can give me your opinion, how you would implement this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my suggestion but I'm also beginner for JavaEE so there might be another way to do.

You need to first established

Parent POM by using Maven inside Parent POM project, put all your dependency then create a modules like

```
parent-project[pom]:
     project-name-data.jar
     project-name-services.jar
     project-name-webservice.war
     project-name-ui.war
```

by this way, You can use all your shared library on your application.

> How should i implement the components with all the database stuff? (I would use EJB, because of the Pooling and the transaction stuff)

It will be done in **project-name-data.jar** and implement on **project-name-services.jar**

> How should i implement the component(s), which are using the native library through JNI, but also have to interact with the database? (Jax-WS WebService, EJB declared as JAX-WS service?

It will be implement in **project-name-webservice.war** by adding JAX-WS service, **project-name-services.jar** dependency.

In Your **project-name-ui.war** add dependency of **project-name-webservice.war** to run your application fine.

If you not clear about this, then [click here](https://github.com/bibekshakya35/payroll). it's my personal tryout which use EJB, Jax-RS and other libraries. Hope it will help you.